# How to refresh picture control in MFC vs2008

Tags: visual-studio-2008, mfc, image, visual-c++

I an a newbie in VC++ and MFC. I am tried to display picture in picture control. The only problem is the control doesn't refresh while I reload another picture. How can I force the picture control refresh before reloading?

Is there any function like "Clear" to empty the picture control for another loading? Thx.

Comment: It is utterly unguessable without code.  Don't be lazy, document your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
// Invalidate window so entire client area 
// is redrawn when UpdateWindow is called.    

Invalidate();

// Update Window to cause View to redraw.

UpdateWindow();
```

this code is used to update window
this will empty the picture control for another loading

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6yz8we9y(v=vs.80).aspx

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are suing a CStatic then just call staticObject.RedrawWindow() after updating the bitmap ...

Answer (score 0):

MFC is bit weird . The original authors are dead and no one knows why it works the way it works .

After you set the icon please write below code

```html
Ctrl.SetIcon(m_htrustIcon);
    Invalidate();
    UpdateWindow();
    Ctrl.RedrawWindow();
```